# MaterialDesign Bootstrap alternative to implement mobile Centric application with data visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is alternative to MaterialDesign Bootstrap in developing responsive web apps with data visualization

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can explore [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) as well.

with a combination of [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) or [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) you will get satisfactory results